# dojo contentpane- how to keep it closed by default

Tags: dojo, dijit.layout

I have set up a layout that contains a few dojo widgets and would like the side menu which has contentpanes to all be closed by default. What happens is that the first one stays open and causes the other contentpanes to disappear. By the way the contentpanes are all within a accordiancontainer

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
   <script src=
     "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5/dojo/dojo.xd.js"
      djConfig="parseOnLoad: true"></script>


    <title>Dijit Template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
      libs/dojo/1.5/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" />
    </head>
    <body class="claro">
    <div style="width: 535px; height: 290px">
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" style="width: 100%; 
     height: 100%;">
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="top" splitter="true">
        This is the content in the top section.
    </div>
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="left" style="width: 100px;" 
      splitter="true">
        <div dojoType="dijit.layout.AccordionContainer"minSize="20" 
         style="width:  300px;" id="leftAccordion" region="leading" splitter="true">
         <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="HOME">
          </div>
         <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="INSTANCES">
          <div dojoType="dijit.TitlePane" title="Reader01">
                    </div>
       </div>
      <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="DISCOVERY">
                  </div>
     </div><!-- end AccordionContainer -->
    </div>
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="center" splitter="true">
        This is the content in the center section.
    </div>
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="right" 
            style="width: 100px;"splitter="true">
        This is the content in the right section.
    </div>
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="bottom" splitter="true">
         This is the content in the bottom section.
     </div>
 </div>
  </div>




</body>
</html>​
```

Comment: what do you want to accomplish by doing that? i mean, what should be 'in' the accordionpane if not one of the panes from onload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the addChild functio of AccorionContainer you will see following lines

```
this.layout();
if(!this.selectedChildWidget){
   this.selectChild(child);
}
```

a child will allways be selected, however lets draw a line here

Try this, it is snippet of your code, adding an empty child ontop of all the other contentpanes (home, instances etc), which we will set selected - and hide onload

```
        <div dojoType="dijit.layout.AccordionContainer"  
         style="width:  300px;" id="leftAccordion" region="leading" splitter="true">
            <script type="dojo/connect" events="onLoad">
                // at this point, children have not yet been added, release and let widget complete workflow
                var acc_container = this;
                setTimeout(function() {
                   // get the child, then hack to get its wrapper (includes titlenode)
                   var hiddenChild = acc_container.getChildren()[0].id+"_wrapper"
                   hiddenChild = dijit.byId(hiddenChild);
                   acc_container._hideChild(hiddenChild);
               }, 100);
            </script>

         <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" dojoProps="selected:true" selected="true">
          </div>
```

Comment: hey perfect...thanks. Does the accordian control allow you to click to open and close each child?

Comment: I have one more follow up question: do you know how I can have a button in the contentpane within the accordian and when it is clicked it displays a tabcontainer within the center area of the borderlayout...something like this I have already  http://jsfiddle.net/trXBr/

Comment: first question, not sure what you mean by that - the accordian has a number of children, one of them is the selected, visible one - once you click the titlepanel of a child - it gets opened and the currently selected child closes

Comment: second; go abouts with what you have in the fiddle, its nearly there, all you need is to write markup for the buttons and give your center contentpane an id (dijit.byId('myContentPane') is undefined). `<div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id="myContentPane"></div>` and `<button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" id="loadBtn">Load contents</button>`.the `layout.ContentPane` has `.attr("content", html|widget|array_of_widgets)` and `.attr("href", url)` functions

Comment: can you help with this please...not sure about the markup to get this to work http://jsfiddle.net/trXBr/3/

Comment: something is not where its supposed to be.. To set the href of a contentpane, which has jsId=pane, you do : `dijit.byId('pane').set("href", url));` is just listed html, widget, array in the `set("content", ?)` to say, it accepts anything you give it rly.. Be it markup, a programmaticcally created widget or even an array of widgets. Can be used to reparent a widget as well

Comment: thanks for your help...http://jsfiddle.net/trXBr/5/...one more sorry: why does dojo.connect(...) not work in IE

Comment: no idea to be honest, does the UI of your button change while clicking and holding left-click on it?